# Combining Javascript Arrays into key value look up

Tags: javascript, arrays, key-value

I have a Javascript object called Data that looks like:

```
Object {
  zip: Array[14631],
  lat: Array[14631],
  lng: Array[14631],
  surge: Array[14631]
}
```

Data looks like

```
Zipcode, Lat,    Lng,    Surge
10025,   47.323, -93.43, 1.7
```

So to access elements I can do something like:
`data['zip'][i]` and it will return the 'ith' element of the zip array.
I can do the same with all the arrays.

What I want is a data structure such that I can do:
`data[10025]` and it will return all matching element in the other arrays.
So lets say I had 5 entries with zipcode = 10025, the data[10025] would return:

```
10025,lat_1,lng_1,surge_1
10025,lat_2,lng_2,surge_2
10025,lat_3,lng_3,surge_3
10025,lat_4,lng_4,surge_4
10025,lat_5,lng_5,surge_5
```

So that I could then double iterate through

```
for zip in data['zip']{
  for i in data[zip] {
    print data[zip]['lats'][i]
  }
}
```

I think this is a simple enough problem but I don't have much experience with javascript and can't seem to get it. Any help is much appreciated.

Another way to phrase this is I would like an object that looks like:

```
    data[array size of N]
```

Where each element of that array holds 3 arrays of size M

Comment: please add some parts of the real data structure.

Comment: What parts do you think I should add?
The real structure is an object with 4 arrays of equal length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do it something like this...

```
data = {
    "10025": [
        {
            "Lat": 47.323,
            "Lng": -93.43,
            "Surge": 1.7
        },{
            "Lat": 47.323,
            "Lng": -93.43,
            "Surge": 1.7
        },{
            "Lat": 47.323,
            "Lng": -93.43,
            "Surge": 1.7
        }
    ]
};
```

Then you could access the zip by data["10025"] and loop through the array of locations.

```
var data = {};
for(var i = 0; i < obj.zip.length;i++){
    var zip = obj.zip[i]
    data[zip] = data[zip] || [];
    data[zip].push({
        zip: obj.zip[i],
        lat: obj.lat[i],
        lng: obj.lng[i],
        surge: obj.surge[i]
    });
}
```

Comment: Ideally that would be the best way to do it. But the data is given to me in the format I described. I want to turn it into the format you describe above.

Comment: James, I added the algorithm to achieve your proposed data structure. Feel free to roll back the edit if you do not agree.

Comment: Thanks guys, that did the trick.
Is there an easy way I can iterate through the zipcodes now that they a keys?

Comment: [Object.keys(data)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 2):

Without changing the original data, you could use the indices of the array in a new array for an object with the zip code as key.

```
data = {
    "10025": [ 2, 4, 7, 10],
    "10027": [ 1, 3, 9, 11],
};
```

Generate data with

```
var data = Object.create(null); // create empty object

object.zip.forEach(function (z, i) {
    data[z] = data[z] || [];
    data[z].push(i);
});
```

Access would be:

```
data[zip].forEach(function (index) {
    // do something with the value ...
    var lat = object.lats[index]
});
```

Comment: How would I do that in Javascript given just the object Data, I described?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Array, keyed by zip code
var zip_array = [];

// Iterate over zip data, building zip_array as we go.
var zip_data = data.zip;
for (var i = 0, len = zip_data.length; i < len; ++i)
{
    var current_zip = zip_data[i];
    if (zip_array[current_zip]){
      zip_array[current_zip].push(getDataAt(i));
    }
  else {
    zip_array[current_zip] = [ getDataAt(i) ];
  }
}

function getDataAt (index)
{
  return [ data.zip[index], data.lat[index], data.lng[index], data.surge[index]].join(",");
}
```

Comment: POST QUESTION-UPDATE:
If you want zip_array to be a 3d array (as you describe), instead of 2d as I have implemented here, then just omit the .join(",") in the final line of getDataAt.